# Box2D (C++) triangle shape failing area assert

Tags: c++, box2d, polygon, shapes, vertex

I'm creating a triangle shaped polygon in Box2D (C++) using this code:

```
b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
b2PolygonShape dynamicPolygon;
b2Vec2 vertices[3];
vertices[0].Set(0, -1);
vertices[1].Set(-1, 1);
vertices[2].Set(1, 1);
dynamicPolygon.Set(vertices, 3);
fixtureDef.shape = &dynamicPolygon;
```

However, upon running this code, I get this error:

```
a.out: ./Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2PolygonShape.cpp:127: b2Vec2 ComputeCentroid(const b2Vec2*, int32): Assertion `area > 1.19209289550781250000e-7F' failed.
```

The area seems to be too small, however, the points should make a correct triangle?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to swap the values of vertices 1 and 2:

```
b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
b2PolygonShape dynamicPolygon;
b2Vec2 vertices[3];
vertices[0].Set(0, -1);
vertices[1].Set(1, 1);
vertices[2].Set(-1, 1);
dynamicPolygon.Set(vertices, 3);
fixtureDef.shape = &dynamicPolygon;
```

This option puts the vertices in counter-clockwise order works...

Comment: Probably because the formula that you use for calculating area is dependent on the vertices order. If we don't see the code is difficult to say that, but considering the error message and how you solved it, it seems to be the reason.

Comment: I think you originally had them clockwise, but you had to put them counter-clockwise. This is the way box2d expects them. From the user manual: "Polygons vertices are stored with a counter clockwise winding (CCW)...."

Comment: Don't think so? In your answer (2nd option that worked), your first vertex is on the y axis, below the x axis, your 2nd vertex is in Quadrant I and third vertex in Quadrant II. So you're defining them in counter-clockwise motion, as b2d expects, thus it worked that way.

Comment: @PeterR Ah, I understand now. I was thinking that the first point was above the other 2, because I was thinking that -1 is higher (like on a screen).